# Sending Json from ASP.Net MVC 5 to Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to make an online store. I want to display a list of products when loading the page. I use in development ASP.Net MVC5 and Vue.js. So far I have this code. How to make the controller send JSON data when loading the page, and Vue accepted and gave them out as a list?

ASP.NET MVC Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    IOrderService orderService;
    public HomeController(IOrderService serv)
    {
        orderService = serv;
    }
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public JsonResult GetAllItem()
    {
        IEnumerable<ItemDTO> itemDTOs = orderService.GetItems();
        var mapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<ItemDTO, ItemViewModel>()).CreateMapper();
        var items = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ItemDTO>, List<ItemViewModel>>(itemDTOs);
        var jsondata = items;
        return Json(jsondata, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Vue.js Index.cshtlm

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            items: []
        },
        mounted() {
            Vue.axios.get('/GetAllItem').then((response) => { this.items = response.data })
        },
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I didn’t wait for an answer, but if anyone is interested, I decided it this way:
Added by Vue-resource. In the vue code changed:

`Vue.axios.get('/GetAllItem').then((response) => { this.items = response.data })`

to

```
this.$http.get('/Home/GetAllItem').then((response) => { this.items = response.data })
```